# PHP regular expression to detect all link href

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need to detect all links. Get an array with all `<a ...>...</a>`.

I tried this but it will get just the last `</a>`.

```
preg_match_all("|<a .+>.*</a>|s", $emailBody, $links);
```

If I skip **s** it works for all expect those that are divided by new lines.

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: please use something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ for this

Comment: `preg_match_all("|<a.+?>.*?</a>|s", $emailBody, $links);`